# How to display only part of the option text in a select when it is not dropped down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop-down select box on a web page to select (e.g.) a customer code - this is a short code used on an existing database to represent the customer.

In order to make the UI easier to use, I would like more information to be displayed in the drop-down than just the code - e.g. the customer full name as well.

However, for reasons of space, I would NOT like the customer name to be displayed in the select box when it is not dropped down, just the code.

Can anyone suggest a reasonably easy way to do this? I am currently using jquery in the project, if that's any help.

To summarise - when the select is closed, I want to just display the customer short code. When it is dropped down, I would like to display both the code and the full name in each select option.

It has occurred to me that I could do this by changing the option text, depending on whether the drop-down is open or not. However, I can't seem to find an event that is triggered when the dropdown opens and closes.

Comment: You want more details on the selected element but less on the unselected ones, and for that to switch when user switches selection? So that when you click on a customer code you get more information in the selected dropdown element for that customer code? Am I correct in my assessment of what you're asking?

Comment: No. When the select is dropped down, I want to see a list of customer codes and names, so the user can select one. When one has been selected (and the drop-down closes) I just want to see the code selected, and not the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just not possible. I'd suggest you build a custom droprown, for example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropdown-label">1234</span>
    <select>
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

In this case, with CSS you can place the `span` on top of the `select` and use `pointer-events: none` so when the user clicks the `span`, the `select` (which is under it) receives the click and opens. Then is just a matter of listening to the select's `change` event to update the label when an option is selected, with whatever you want to display.

Comment: Pity there is not an already written control that does this. What CSS would I use to position a span on top of the select (ideally not obscuring the drop-down arrow)? I could do it in javascript, but it would be complicated (because the size may change depending on the data content and the window size).

Comment: Keeping the select arrow will be hard, as each browser has it's own design for the select. I'd suggest to make your own dropdown arrow (as a background image or with an icon like font awesome). You should use `position: relative` in the `div` and then `position: absolute` in the `span` and the `select` to place them one on top the other. Use `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` to position them and assign a greater `z-index` to the `span`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text of the selected dropdown item with `$('.dropdown option:selected').text("text")` and use javascript `string.split()` on the value (likely whitespace) that separates the customer code from the name.

Comment: Surely that would only show the name on the selected option? I want all the names to appear when the dropdown is open (to help the user choose one), but the name not to appear when the dropdown is closed.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood!

Answer (score 0):

I liked a lot the answer from [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1365104/gabriel)
but I have not enough experience with CSS, so I decided to show the full answer
with a very useful example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <style>
    #the_td_of_time_zone{
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
    }

    #the_span{
        /*To align text horizontally and vertically inside the parent*/
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 20px; /* The same as your parent height */
        pointer-events: none; /*allow the click to pass through the element*/
        position: absolute; /*To help overlap Zone with dropdown*/
        z-index: 100; /*To put the Zone on top of the dropdown*/
        background-color: #006699; /*To match with Admin Menu background*/
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0px;
        text-decoration: None;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    }
    #the_select{
        position: absolute;
    }
    </style>


    <div id="the_td_of_time_zone">
        <span id="the_span">Time Zone</span>
        <select id="the_select">
            <option>uno</option>
            <option>dos</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```